# Error Module named Flask using Virtualenv

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to execute pgadmin4 using a virtualenv.

```
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate
pip install pgadmin4-4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sudo python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Follow this sequence, I checked which my env was activated, once I see (pgadmin4) before path file. Flask installed, checked in pip list, but even so this error keeping happening

```
(pgadmin4) PC@PC-Latitude-3470:~/Documents/pgadmin4$ sudo python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 40, in <module>
    import config
  File "/home/PC/Documents/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_PY2, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/home/PC/Documents/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Outside from my virtualenv, I do not have Flask installed, but is not necessary, I just want to use Flask in my virtualenv

Comment: If you sudo python you're no longer using the python found in your virtualenv. I believe the sudo -E flag will help you. Otherwise, root up first, then activate your virtualenv

Comment: from here: `(pgadmin4) PC@PC-Latitude-3470:~/Documents/pgadmin4$` if you run `pip install Flask` does that fix it? I see `Flask` is not in your original `pip install` command

Comment: @MaxPower I already did `pip install flask`

Comment: @Kamori You're right, but if I do not use sudo I receive a  `Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin'` error. Should I use chmod in this folder?

Comment: @ThiagoL it's hard to say based on your needs. You can still use your virtual env python as root and with sudo. But do this instead  sudo bin/python lib/pyrhon/path/to/pgAdmin4.py

Comment: @Kamori, Again, you're right, I used `su` leveling as a root and executed pgadmin4. Worked it!